# acceptance rejection algorithm c++ normal distribution

Tags: c++, numerical-methods

The general Accept rejection algorithm is as usual .

1 generate U 1 ,U 2 ,U 3 from Unif[0,1]

2  X ← −log(U 1 )

3  if U 2 > exp(−0.5(X − 1) 2 ).... go back until condition met.

My question is do I need to use separate seed for each uniform distribution or using the same seed?

Comment: Your need for different seeds "for each uniform distribution" depends on what you are going to use the distributions for. Also, I am not perfectly sure what a single uniform distribution is for you. Could you please explain?

Comment: @Peter G  basically u have 2 plot, f(x) and g(x) and u are guaranteed M*g(x)>=f(x), then u only accept numbers if u2<f(x)/M*g(x).And x is generated using -log(u1),,, And i thought i need different seeds as [[[[U2 can be the same same U1]]]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the same seed – as in, **you must seed the generator only once**. What’s more, you should use only one generator: there is no reason to use more than one, and it’s easy to introduce subtle errors with more than one.

Technically, for a good enough PRNG it doesn’t matter (as long as the seeds are distinct) but it won’t hurt either. For an inferior PRNG, using separate seeds may skew your results significantly if the seeds are correlated in any way (and they practically often are unless you seed from a true random device).

Be sure to use the new `<random>` standard header in C++! `std::rand` should be considered deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I gather that the question is if the pseudo random number generators (PRNGs) used to generate the helper variables in acceptance rejection algorithms should be seeded differently.

You cannot have good statistical properties without a good PRNG, therefore before thinking about seeding, choose a good generator. Given a good generator, you don't need to use different seeds in your use case of creating two independent distributions. In fact, you could accidently (even if very unlikely with a good generator) choose an especially bad combination of seeds, leading to statistical anomalies.

Fortunately, as of C++11 you are usually supplied with good PRNGs in the header [`<random>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/). My default choice is the [Mersenne Twister](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/mersenne_twister_engine/). I take it you want to generate normal distributions by manually coded acceptance rejection as practice or due to some other requirement. If not, C++11 already provides you with a ready to use [normal distribution](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/normal_distribution/).

Answer (score -1):

You have to use different seeds, since if you use the same seed, then your random variables will have a covariance of 1.

Comment: This answer is too brief to be clear. I'm not going to call it wrong yet.

Comment: Depends on how you interpret the question. If he generates the values from the same random generator, then it needs only one seed. If he generates U1, U2, U3 from three random generators, then he needs different seeds for them.

Comment: @Tamás *And* he needs to guarantee that the seeds are unrelated. And there is no reason to use three generators instead of one.

Comment: @KonradRudolph that's correct. But the question reads "do I need to use separate seed for **each** uniform distribution or using the same seed". Since he used the word "each", I supposed he wanted to use more than 1 generator.

Comment: @Tamás Zahola After some thought i'll go with different seeds. As I don't think the algorithm rules out the possibility that U2 has to be different compared to U1.

Comment: @XunBao It *does* rule it out. The concept of different generator engines doesn’t make sense to begin with.